# WinHttpSendRequest failed with error code 87

Tags: windows, c++11, winapi

I'm trying to download a file from a server using WinHttpSendRequest but the result is 0 and error code is 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

```
// Specify an HTTP server.
if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, T2W((LPTSTR)tsDownloadServer.c_str()), wPort, 0 );
// tsDownloadServer = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx"

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET",T2W((LPTSTR)tsDownloadFileURLPath.c_str()), NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, ppwszAcceptTypes, dwOpenRequestFlag );
// tsDownloadFileURLPath = "/xxxxx/xxxxxxxx/58bbf9067ad35634c7caa5594e8ec712/windows_installer/xxxxx_xxxxxx.wak"

bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0 );
```

bResults is 0 and GetLastError() return 87

I researched on the internet about the related issue is due to exceed 24 bytes data however in my case, I set WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA in the parameter.

How can I send a request to the server?

Comment: Forget WinHTTP and use WinInet.

Comment: Have you seen that bResults, from  WinHttpOpenRequest, is not NULL? it could be the reason that you have an ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (87)result.

Comment: The code is clearly being compiled with Unicode enabled, so my magic crystal debugger thinks `tsDownloadServer` and `tsDownloadFileURLPath` are ANSI strings being incorrectly typecasted into invalid Unicode character pointers. If you have to typecast just to make the code compile, you are likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` means that the issue is on handler `hRequest`, which you have not checked the return value yet. If it is NULL, that maybe the cause was on the last call `WinHttpOpenRequest`; or even `WinHttpConnect` was failed, so that it didn't get `hRequest` any more.

As @Remy Lebeau said, it depends on your Unicode setting. With Unicode disabled, if the type of `tsDownloadServer` and `tsDownloadFileURLPath` is `wstring`, then `(LPTSTR)tsDownloadServer.c_str()` will be convert from wide char to multiple bytes. Then the zero in the wide character(If the character is in ASCII) is considered the terminator:
[image]

And the string is truncated:
[image]